# How to clean a view's UITableView for a next reload?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I do this:

```
controllerData = [[Data alloc] initWithNibName:@"Data" bundle:nil];

controllerData.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[delegate.navigationControllerMenu presentModalViewController:controllerData animated:YES];
```

Then I get a view with a tableview and their cells. If I execute "[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];" this view is dropped like I want to, but If load the view again I get a tableview with duplicate rows.

Do you know how can I avoid the duplicate rows when I reload the view?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

EDIT:

I load the items like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    

DataCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[DataCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}  

int fila = indexPath.row;
DataManager *dataManager = [DataManager sharedDataManager];
DataTest *ob = [dataManager.dataArray objectAtIndex:fila];  
cell.usuario.text = ob.usuario;       
cell.fecha.text = ob.fecha;    
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably adding your array items to the datasource again. Check how you add the items and make sure you dont add them everytime you load the modalview

Comment: Hello, the matter is that I do want to add them everytime because the data maybe have changed. I would have to remove the old items and load the new ones.

Comment: Yes. Put the array in a temp and clear the one you use as datasource. Then use the temp with ur data and update it. When your data is updated set it back to the datasource and you will never have duplicates anymore

Comment: Sorry, I am very noob and I don't know what you want to say. How do I clear the array I use as datasource? I use an array of objects. Are you saying if I clear that array the view doesn't load the items? I've just added more information to my main question.

Comment: I only want to destroy all signs of the created view, as if it had never loaded.